# Is Drools 6.0 WB same as Drools 5.5 Guvnor?

Tags: drools

I have started working with Drools and all the documentation talks about Guvnor for deployment.

Is the Drools 6.0 WB same as Drools 5.5 Guvnor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools 6 Workbench is the replacement for Guvnor. However it is much richer. Take a look at the videos of it to see some of this:

http://blog.athico.com/2013/12/drools-60-workbench-and-editor-videos.html

Just be warned that it is very new, and there are teething troubles. You may also have difficulty getting it to work on anything other than the JBoss AS application server.